# Security Context Returning Null value in Web App

Tags: spring, spring-security, vaadin

In my web application the security context is with a value of (org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@ffffffff: Null authentication) 
and on doing some search I found something like : 
"Look to see if you have any references to SecurityContextHolder in your code. If you do, ensure that you have the SecurityContextPersistenceFilter place on any URLs that could invoke that code."

In my Project this filter is created but I dont know what exactly this means.

Can someone please give me some advice?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you have something like

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFitler</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSeurityFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

in your `web.xml` descriptor file.

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/html/security-filter-chain.html for more info.

Also note that in a Vaadin application you usually want to exclude some paths in security context file, for example:

```
<http pattern="/VAADIN/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/HEARBEAT/**" security="none" />
```

Comment: What is HEARBEAT?

Comment: @KorayTugay vaadin-clients send a keep-alive request (hearbeat) at heartbeatInterval (5 minutes by default).  The server side clean up the client  UIs when there are no request from client and the hearbeat is not received for a while.